# Keycloak Docker import users

Tags: docker, keycloak

## Abstract

I need a pre-configured keycloak instance deployed **automatically** during tests.
Importing users into Keycloak seems to be a challenge

## Approach

I created a Docker container with predefined Realm/Users/Clients
Using the export / import feature I can easily rebuild a Realm with clients, but not Users.
To be clear, Users shows up in the JSON file. So the export looks legit.

## Desperate Attempts

I have tried multiple approaches including, but not limited to:

1. `ENV KEYCLOAK_IMPORT my-realm.json` in the docker file => <kbd>Realm ✔</kbd> <kbd>Clients  ✔</kbd> <kbd>Users ✖</kbd>

Did not create Users but was perfect in term of workflow. It runs during the docker build.

2. Import through `docker exec ... action=import` => <kbd>Realm ✔</kbd> <kbd>Clients  ✔</kbd> <kbd>Users ✖</kbd>

```
docker exec -it <id> /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100 -Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile -Dkeycloak.migration.realmName=myrealm -Dkeycloak.migration.file=/tmp/my-realm.json
```

3. Set the `Strategy: OVERWRITE_EXISTING` for users and provider to `singleFile`. to have everything in one go.
4. Manually import through the admin console, <kbd>Realm ✖</kbd> <kbd>Clients  ✔</kbd> <kbd>Users ✔</kbd>

[image: Keycloak console screenshot]

Clearly not a good fit for automation, but at least my JSON users are importable.

## Hence

Is there some cheat code environemt variable like `KEYCLOAK_FULL_IMPORT` that does everything in one go in the Dockerfile?

Comment: What about creating DB docker image with preconfigured testing keycloak database and then running keycloak + DB containers together?

Comment: @solveMe that could work indeed

Answer (score 8):

I confess with limited pride this was a stupid typo in my Dockerfile

For short I was copying from the wrong file. The proper configuration looked like this

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:latest

COPY my-realm.json /tmp/my-realm.json

ENV KEYCLOAK_USER admin
ENV KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD admin

ENV DB_VENDOR h2

ENV KEYCLOAK_IMPORT /tmp/my-realm.json
```

The typo was `COPY some-realm.json /tmp/my-realm.json` where `some-realm.json` did actually not include users.